# My laptop boots into automatic repair not to windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios, passwords

I had an administrator password for bios, which I forgot and gave wrong password thrice on it. After that the system boots to Automatic Repair and not to Windows 10.

I tried several repair option, Startup repair and resetting the device, Nothing was successful.

Will resetting BIOS Password help me in this case?
Does Bios Write Protected my hard disk for entering Wrong password?

Comment: Administrator password for BIOS does not affect boot. Are you sure you don't also have a BIOS User password, and have you by mistake set both to the same password?

Comment: I don't have bios user password. It does boot continuously into automatic repair.

Comment: Do you mean you did a Reset of Windows and the problem still happens? How did you Reset when you can't boot?

Comment: Windows Boots into Automatic repair mode.

Comment: Option like Resetting windows and startup repair are there but It gives an error. It didnt reset.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [Harrymc](https://superuser.com/questions/1485030/my-laptop-boots-into-automatic-repair-not-to-windows-10/1485060#1485060) said, BIOS admin password doesn't affect booting of the system. It might be just a coincidence.

You can try [Automatic Repair Loop](https://www.technology.org/2017/11/14/7-ways-fix-stuck-in-windows-automatic-repair-loop) in order to solve the issue.

If this doesn't solve your problem you can use [Repair Install of Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) or install it again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the wrong password is incidental to the problem. The BIOS usually forgets
about this problem when you turn the computer off.

Windows setup was somehow destroyed and need to be fixed.

Start first with
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This is equivalent to upgrading Windows 10 to version 1903,
so is not very destructive.

If this does not help, you will need to re-install Windows.
If you have files to save and Windows is not booting, use a Linux Live USB
to save your files first.